# How To make varbinary type maximum in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have Question, in my application needed setting type for varbinary in my database i have 8 field name using varbinary(max), like as using sql server varbinary(max) but i already did varbinary(60000) that's is not problem database still running fine, but after i tried to using varbinary(60000) for each field name, showing error like below [image: 1]

can someone help me for solving this problem i have tried to setting ROW_FORMAT to COMPRESSED,DYNAMIC but still cannot set varbinary(60000) for each field name.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, MySQL has row size limit of 65535. You can change the columns to use `TEXT` datatype so you won't hit the row size limit.

See [MySQL documentation - Limits on Table Column Count and Row Size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html) for more info.

Comment: thank you for you'r answer, i have already tried like varbinary(60000) for each field but still showing error sql error 1118. maybe how can we update size table because i have tried to upgrade innodb_log_file_size to 256M but still showing 1118, thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try using `TEXT`?

Comment: `VARCHAR`- and `VARBINARY`-columns are stored into the row and are hence subject to the row max size. `TEXT`-columns, on the other hand, are stored separately and have not such restriction.

Comment: thanks for you'r answer, yes i already tried using LONG BLOB or TEXT that's work fine for each field. but can we force using varbinary(60000) or varbinary(max) ?.  maybe do you have more tips for using varbinary(60000) for each field. because for read hexbinary from fingerprint engine, but if mysql does'nt support it. maybe i will try using TEXT. thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you want to use `VARBINARY`? `VARBINARY` is stored in the row and therefore breaking the max row size. `BLOB` can hold the same data as the `VARBINARY` and if you are storing long binary data, you should use  `BLOB`. You can use `BLOB` (up to 64Kb), `MEDIUMBLOB`  (up to 16mb) or even `LONGBLOB` (up to 4Gb).

Comment: thank you for you'r answer, i need using varbinary because for read hexbinary data from fingerprint device, i tried using sql server like varbinary(max) and try to scan my finger that's work fine. but i need using mysql with similar type like as varbinary(max) that's can't,  so i tried varbinary(60000) for each field still can't. so i tried  using long blob and then system fingerprint doesn't want to scan my finger or system can't read because using different type. maybe do you have more tips for me similar type like as varbinary because i already using all type blob thanks in advance

Comment: A `BLOB` stands for “Binary Large Object”, so it is the datatype you should use. If you have trouble storing the data, your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: thank you for you'r answer. maybe error otherplace or type data for reading. but thanks for you'r answer, if i have more question i will ask again thanks in advance.